# How to compare input and list content (and handle wrong inputs)

Tags: python, input

This piece of code will ask for input, compare input with content of lists and, if input and content match, return input.
If input is not in list user will be asked again for input.

```
def get_input(tested_list):

    corect_input = False

    while not corect_input:
        try:
            # we are comparing input to list of lists content
            my_input = str.lower((input("Enter here: ")))
            for line in a_list:
                if my_input == line[2].lower():
                    return my_input
        except ValueError:
            print("????")
        else:
            corect_input = False
```

Now questions (I'm very beginner. Try-Except-Else is all very new for me) :

- Is there any reason here to include 'except' line? Since input is converted to string, I can't see way to input anything what will cause any error.
- What kind of error shall I use after 'except'.
- How shall I write this piece of code to be better / cleaner/ more pythonic? :) .

thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First issue to note is that `a_list` in your function should be replaced by `tested_list`. `a_list` has not been defined and will cause an error.

There are at least 2 possible errors you can face:

1. `AttributeError`, if the 2nd index of a sublist in `tested_list` is not a string, e.g. if it is an integer.
2. `IndexError`, if the 2nd index of a sublist in `tested_list` does not exist, e.g. if the sublist is of length 2.

However, to make your `try` / `except` clause useful in this context, you need to define it within the `for` loop. Below is an example.

```
def get_input(tested_list):

    correct_input = False

    while not correct_input:
        my_input = str.lower((input("Enter here: ")))
        for line in tested_list:
            try:
                if my_input == line[2].lower():
                    return my_input
            except (AttributeError, IndexError):
                print("An error has occurred")
        else:
            correct_input = False
```